# Differentiating a function defined by more than one rule, and finding where the function is increasing and decreasing.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a two simple questions.
Yesterday my math teacher was differentiating this function $f(x)=x|x|$
first he split the function into two.
$f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x^2  & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
  -x^2 & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$
and after differentiating he wrote it like that.
$f\backprime(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  2x  & \mbox{if } x > 0 \\
  -2x & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$

why he removed the equal sign from the domain of the first rule?
it became $x>0$ instead of $x \geq 0$

Another question, i solved this function as follows "the function is increasing over $\mathbb{R}-(0)$" but he solved it as follows "the function is increasing over $\mathbb{R}$"

Answer (score 0):

I think your teacher wrote that to make clear the fact that the case of $0$ have to be treated separately because your function is not defined the same way on the right and left side of that point. Derivatives only have a sense on open sets.
To prove the differentiability on $0$, you can compute :
$$f'_+(0)=\lim_{ x\to 0+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0},f'_-(0)=\lim_{ x\to 0-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
If $f'_+(0)=f'_-(0)$ and $f$ is continous on $0$ (don't forget this), then the function is differentiable on $0$ and $f'(0)=f'_+(0)$.

EDIT

$[0,\infty[$ isn't an open set, so the derivative is senseless on $0$ (unless you prove it separately, for example with the method I gave you). But more importantly, you don't need to know that the function is differentiable at $0$ in order to conclude that $f$ is increasing over $\mathbb{R}$.

The function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, its derivative is always positive on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ : so $f$ is increasing over $\mathbb{R}$.

If we set $g(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \sqrt x  & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
  x & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$

Now won't have $g$ differentiable on $0$, but $g$ is still increasing over $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that you need continuity ir order to conclude this.

Comment: And in this case the function is differentiable at 0, why he removed the quality then?

Comment: @Mohaimn Draz Edited

Comment: Sorry about that, but I don't get it. If the function is differentiable at x=0, so why he removed the equality as I asked in the first place??? If the function is differentiable at x=0 the it should be increasing over R-{0}

Comment: You are correct about the inequality. It should be inclusive. Regarding the increasing, the proposition that you are trying to use (positive derivative implies increasing) does not say that a derivative of zero at a value means that it's not increasing (consider $f(x) =x^3$, x=0).